# Proguard can't find referenced class when run "gradlew build" the first time

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm using gradle to build my android project and ran into a rather strange problem.

When I run "gradlew build" for the first time, build will break due to proguard can't find referenced class. However, when I run "gradlew build" again, build can successfully finish.

```
D:\project\abs-demo>gradlew clean
D:\project\abs-demo>gradlew build     // first time, fail
D:\project\abs-demo>gradlew build     // second time, succeed
```

Error messages are as follows:

```
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionItems: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionModes: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionModes$AnActionModeOfEpicProportions: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode$Callback
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionModesNoActionBar: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionModesNoActionBar$AnActionModeOfEpicProportions: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode$Callback
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionProviders: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.ActionProviders$SettingsActionProvider: can't find superclass or interface com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider
....
```

I'm using gradle 0.7. And my build.gralde:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.0"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I uploaded [my project here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PMpiapRslMSDkyMGpBUnhqV1E/edit?usp=sharing).

Do I do something wrong? Or it is a bug of gradle?

Comment: I have the same problem when using gradle from path. First build fails, second is ok.

So: 
"gradle clean assembleDebug"
"gradle clean build"

 works fine if executed in sequence:(

Comment: Sounds like the Proguard task runs too early and operates on the classes produced by the *previous* build invocation.

Comment: Could you add some details... Which version of the Gradle plugin are you using? Does lib have its own build.gradle? Is PullToRefresh a source file or a library jar? I can't seem to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EricLafortune I uploaded a demo project that can reproduce my problem. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in the Android Gradle plugin, versions 0.7.0 and 0.7.1: [issue 63944](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63944) and [issue 64039](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64039).